# Possible reasons connection initialization order matters when connecting to multiple mysql databases

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm using node.js and the mysql2 package to connect to two databases that reside in two different remote servers.  Lets call them A and B.

What are the possible reasons connection order matters when connecting to multiple mysql databases?

When I connect to A first then B, connection A is successful but connection B is not and simply hangs indefinitely without any errors.

However, when I connect to B first then A, both connection A and B are successful.

Why is this?

Unfortunately I can't provide any error logs, because the connection hangs when unsuccessful.

### index.js

```
(async () => {
  await A.init();  //successfully connects
  await B.init(); //connection hangs with no error log

  app.listen(8080)
})();

(async () => {
  await B.init(); //successfully connects
  await A.init(); //successfully connects

  app.listen(8080)
})();
```

### A and B module

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({...})

module.exports.init = function() {
  return new Promise(function(res, req) {
    connection.connect(err => {
      if(err) return rej(err);

      res(null)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Two databases on the same server, or two different servers?

Comment: two different servers.